# why [].append(1) is None

Tags: python

I use Python like this

```
>>>print [].append(1)
None

>>>ls = []
>>>ls.append(1)
>>>ls
[1]
```

why "[].append(1)" value is None ,and other one is real value?

Comment: If you do `print ls.append(1)` it will become clearer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the `append()` list method doesn't return the list, it just modifies the list it was called on. In this case, an anonymous list is modified and then thrown away.

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) isn't super-clear, but all it says is:

> list.append(x)
>
> Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to `a[len(a):] = [x]`.

For other methods, such as `list.count(x)`, the word "return" occurs in the description, implying that if it doesn't, the method doesn't have a return value.

Comment: it is a pythonic custom to have mutators without return values

Answer (score 0):

`append()` does not return the list it modifies, but

> Append the object item at the end of list list.
>   Return 0 if successful;
>   return -1 and set an exception if unsuccessful.

see http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html

Comment: You are linking to the internal C api documentation - the correct link is http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html or http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html for Python 3.

Comment: That return value is for the internal C API though, it doesn't seem the Python-level call is returning 0 since the OP is showing it returns `None`.

Comment: you are right, this is not ideal. the higher level python docs however are not explicit on what is returned, so you do not get a meaningful quote over there.