# How to write list's data to excel sheet on each "for" loop iterations

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a "for" loop where I iterate each time to get new values stored in same variable, now i want to store the value stored in the list variable in each rows in excel.

what i tried which doesn't works,

```
final_result = []
for i in range(0, 3):
    result_list = ['csm_biscuit_main_dev-7188-userdevsigned', 'Logd', 'G0B0LF036224003G', 'Biscuit', 'completed', '1:47:54', 'completed']
    
    . #some functions, which will keep changing the values in "result_list"
    .
    . 

    final_result = final_result.append(result_list)
    wb = Workbook()
    sh1 = wb.active
    sh1.append(result_list)
    wb.save("Report.xlsx")
    print(final_result)
```

what I am getting is, for each iterations (0, 1, 2) I am getting last iteration's value stored in Report.xlsx.

is there any suggestions to get all iteration's values one by one in rows of excel sheet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why \[\].append(1) is None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610627/why-append1-is-none)

Comment: PS: To make this a [mre], remove all the Excel/Workbook stuff. It's not relevant for your question, since the problem can easily be reproduced by only printing `final_result`.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the problem here..

Comment: Then please clarify the problem. Update your question with expected and actual output. Since this isn't a [mre], I can't test it and so have to guess what's the problem. I see that you do `final_result = final_result.append(result_list)`, which doesn't make any sense, as explained in the duplicate target. If this isn't the problem that your question is about, then please remove that from the code.

Comment: if you write in loop then maybe you need to open file in `append mode`. Or maybe you should create `Workbook()` before loop

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `Workbook()` before loop. That's all.

Using `Workbook()` inside loop you create new workbook in every iteration and this removes previous content - and finally you get valur only for last iteration.

---

Minimal working code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

# --- before loop ---

final_result = []

wb = Workbook()
sh1 = wb.active

# --- loop ---

for i in range(0, 3):
    result_list = ['csm_biscuit_main_dev-7188-userdevsigned', 'Logd', 'G0B0LF036224003G', 'Biscuit', 'completed', '1:47:54', 'completed']
    
    # some functions, which will keep changing the values in "result_list"

    sh1.append(result_list)
    #wb.save("Report.xlsx")

    final_result.append(result_list)
    print(final_result)

# --- after loop ---

wb.save("Report.xlsx")
```